# Double super wildcard

Tags: java, generics, lambda, wildcard, comparator

In this code I have an error on the second line while the first one successfully compiles:

```
Comparator<? super Integer> a = (x, y) -> Integer.compare(x, y);
Comparator<? super Integer> b = a.thenComparing((x, y) -> Integer.compare(x, y));
```

The error is *"incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to int"*

`thenComparing` has following signature: `thenComparing(Comparator<? super T> other)`,
so as I understand `other` in this context will become something like
`Comparator<? super super T>` or `Comparator<? super super Integer>`.

Why in my example it becomes `Comparator<Object>`?

Is this a compiler flaw or is it guarding me from something?

Comment: Which IDE and/or compiler are you using?

Comment: @MCEmperor IntelliJ IDEA / OpenJDK

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: *"incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to int"* I guess

Comment: @Amongalen yes, _error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to int_

Comment: @GhostCat The code in the question is a [mcve] though.

Comment: It didn't contain the exact error message/details ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're defining `a` as a `Comparator<? super Integer>`, and your assignment `(x, y) -> Integer.compare(x, y)` fulfills it.

However, the compiler does not know what exact type `?` is. It could be an `Object`, a `Number` or an `Integer` itself, but *which* one is not known. `thenComparing()` relies on the type argument of `a`, for its signature is `Comparator<T> thenComparing(Comparator<? super T>)`. You are passing in a `Comparator<Integer>`, but `a`'s type argument does not match.

**Generics are invariant**. A `Comparator<? super Integer>` is not a `Comparator<Integer>`. Use the wildcard only if you don't care about the type. Otherwise, use the proper type argument.

Define `a` as a `Comparator<Integer>` in order to fix it.

---

Here's an excellent answer to another Stackoverflow post, explaining *why* generics are not implicitly polymorphic. It also explains what would be the problem if generics were.

- [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po/2745306)

Comment: So this is a compiler limitation? And such code would be safe otherwise?

Comment: It is an *intended* compiler limitation: the compiler stops you because it cannot guarantee type safety anymore.

Comment: But is there an example where this code could lead to a runtime error?

Comment: Why use `? super Integer`? Integer is a final class so it can't be the super class of anything.  Just use `Integer`.

Comment: @WJS Just an example. It could be any class.

Comment: Well, I cannot think of such an example at the moment, but the thing is that the compiler cannot *prove* that this is right. Just like `if (myAnimal instanceof Dog) { myAnimal.bark(); }` won't compile either.

Comment: I've found a good example why this limitation makes sense:

`List<? super Integer> myList = Arrays.asList(42, new Object());`
`myList.sort((x, y) -> Integer.compare(x, y));`

Where `List.sort(...)` has the same signature as `Comparator.thenCompare(...)`.